# How to call another member function when operator overloading (C++)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How would I use a member function (in this case, `magnitude()`) within my definition for the function overload of the greater than operator `>`? The operator should compare the magnitudes of two objects of the class`Vector2D` from which `magnitude()` is also a member.  I receive the following:

> error C2662: 'double Vector2D::magnitude(void)' : cannot convert 'this' >pointer from 'const Vector2D' to 'Vector2D &'

```
 #include <iostream>
        #include <math.h>
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;

        //***************************  Class Definition  ***************************

        class Vector2D {
        public:
            double i, j;
            Vector2D();                     // Default constructor
            Vector2D(double, double);       // Constructor for initializing
            double  magnitude();            // compute and return the magnitude
            bool operator> (const Vector2D& right); // greater than                      
        };

        //function definitions:

        //default constructor
        Vector2D::Vector2D() {
            i = 1;
            j = 1;

        }
        /* constructor*/
        Vector2D::Vector2D(double x, double y) {
            i = x;
            j = y;
        }

        /* magnitude funciton */
        double Vector2D::magnitude()
        {
            return sqrt(pow(i, 2) + pow(j, 2));
        }

       ******* //greater than Overload ************

        bool Vector2D::operator> (const Vector2D& right) {
            if (magnitude() > right.magnitude())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    ***********************************************
```

Comment: bool operator> (const Vector2D& right) **const**; double  magnitude() **const**;

Comment: Off-topic, but unless you're being paid per line, you can reduce that mess to `return magnitude() > right.magnitude();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your functions aren't declared `const`, so can't be applied to constant objects. That's easy to fix:

```
double  magnitude() const;
bool operator> (const Vector2D& right) const;
```

If efficiency is important, you might like to avoid the unnecessary square-root when comparing magnitudes:

```
double square_magnitude() const {return i*i + j*j;}
bool operator> (const Vector2D& right) const {
    return square_magnitude() > right.square_magnitude();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two changes:

- `bool Vector2D::operator> (const Vector2D& right) const`
- `double Vector2D::magnitude() const`

All read-only functions should be marked **const**. You may solve the error by just removing `const` from parameter of your `> operator`, but that would not be good.